# Keep sections are being removed on generation

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I am using GreenDAO v1.2.0 to generate entity classes for an Android app.

I have set enableKeepSectionsByDefault() on my schema, and am getting these comment lines in my generated classes:

```
// KEEP METHODS - put your custom methods here
// KEEP METHODS END
```

I have put some custom methods between the comments, but the custom methods are removed every time I regenerate.

Is there something else I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: same problem here - most code files work, but one simply kills my added code

Answer (score 3):

There is a parsing bug in greenDAO that will cause some or all of your `KEEP METHODS` to get wiped out by running the `DaoGenerator.generateAll()` method (even with `schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault()` enabled)

The bug is that your `Entity` class (the one you have added custom imports, fields or methods to) REQUIRES a blank line at the end of the file.

for example

```
...
    //KEEP_METHODS_END
}
... end of file
```

will fail, while

```
...
    //KEEP_METHODS_END
}

... end of file
```

will work.  Nasty little bug.  Until it's fixed (if ever), ensure that your entity classes have a blank line at the end.

Hope this saves someone the torment I have experienced.

Ensure that the last line of the generated entity class is blank.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();`.

Comment: you mean @yigit I should call it before generation or after it? I have already generated my classes and I am using them!!